# Can anyone clarify this Typescript handbook explanation for `keyof` please?

Tags: typescript

The explanation of `keyof` for index signatures in the Typescript handbook makes no sense.

From here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/keyof-types.html

The following example is presented:

```
type Arrayish = { [n: number]: unknown };
type A = keyof Arrayish;
    
// type A = number
 
type Mapish = { [k: string]: boolean };
type M = keyof Mapish;
    
// type M = string | number
```

With the explanation:

> Note that in this example, `M` is `string | number` — this is because JavaScript object keys are always coerced to a `string`, so `obj[0]` is always the same as `obj["0"]`.

That makes no sense.

What is different about type `M` isn't the presence of the `string` type, since the index was declared as `string` in the first place, what's different is the presence of the `number` type which the explanation does not address.

Also if the type `string` is present because "object keys are always coerced to a string", then why is `string` not listed as one of the key types for type `A` where the index is of declared type `number`?

UPDATE In response to H.Bs answer

`If the key is specified to be number, then only number is allowed because not every string can be converted to a number.`

But the following both compiles and runs, suggesting that specifiing the index using either `number` or `string` is valid in Typescript and Javascript irrespective of the difference in the Typescript type of the indexed access type.

```
let a1: Arrayish = {};
a1[0] = 4;
a1["2"] = 6; // Index declared as number but can be set with string.
console.log(a1);

let m1: Mapish = {};
m1[0] = true;
m1["2"] = false;
console.log(m1);
```

(Tested in the [Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKFBcE8AcFMAICCAnZBDSBLAzgC3gLzwDe8A2gHYBc8FArgLYBGsyAujXRQNYUD2AdwrwAvgG4IMBIkLxusSHwBmSVBhy4JYEABtY4eGgCMNFOix5ZxcaGNkADG1kAWLXYBEAJndOiANi0AYz4KbD49ADodPgBzAApjAEoteEk4eABZNGgNK3JuGmxwZEwKGI54Jj5w2DRhGxAodIzZeUUVLJy8LVA9AwYTTOzcomstAYdfeGK6WHGjMi8fWSU0HWw50GDQmqjYuIHk0CA))

Comment: I agree this distinction is confusing. It seems that array indices are also internally coerced to strings in JS, according to [the mozilla docs on Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array). Nitpick: could you word the title as a question? It currently sounds like a bug report.

Comment: This should be filed on TypeScript's repo instead of on StackOverflow. Only they have the power to effect changes to their own documentation.

Comment: @Terry The problem is that nowadays every open source project rejects any issue that might be a support request and directs users to SO instead. While at the same time SO edgelords vote to close anything that isn't a coding problem. Leaving ordinary users screwed for anywhere to ask a simple question.

Comment: @Neutrino this is so true. SOmetimes a question on SO can be closed in several seconds :D It is frustrating

Answer (score 1):

I would think of it in terms of valid conversions.

If the key is specified to be `number`, then only number is allowed because not every `string` can be converted to a number. If the key is specified as `string` however, then `number` becomes valid as well, because all numbers can be turned into strings, and that is what happens implicitly in JS.

Comment: This seems like a situation where is could be a valid conversion, but Typescript enforces all developers to automatically support this conversion, even if they don't want to. If I want my project to be strict and avoid implicit index coercion, `keyof` doesn't allow me